# Display the sale order customer reference field in the delivery order view

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm attempting to display the customer reference as a read only field in the Delivery orders form view.

I added a related field to the stock.picking.out model:

```
class stock_picking_out(osv.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.picking.out"
    _columns = {
        'cust_order_ref': fields.related('sale_id', 'client_order_ref', type='char', string='Customer Reference'),
    }
```

I inherited the delivery order view with the following block:

```
<record id="view_stock_picking_out_extended_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.picking.out.extended.form</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking.out</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_out_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath  expr="//field[@name='origin']" position="after">
                <field name="client_order_ref" />
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

When I install my custom module, I do see the model getting updated with the new field, and I also see the new field appear in the delivery order view. **However, the values of this field are always empty, even if there is a customer order reference in the related sale order (sale_id)**. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with blow code, Before add any new field in this object *stock.picking.in* or *stock.picking.out*, we need to add it into parent class *stock.picking.*

```
class stock_picking(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'
    _columns = {
        'cust_order_ref': fields.related('sale_id', 'client_order_ref', type='char', string='Customer Reference'),
    }

class stock_picking_out(osv.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.picking.out"
    _columns = {
        'cust_order_ref': fields.related('sale_id', 'client_order_ref', type='char', string='Customer Reference'),
    }
```

Please change your .xml file to.

```
<record id="view_stock_picking_out_extended_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">stock.picking.out.extended.form</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking.out</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_out_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath  expr="//field[@name='origin']" position="after">
            <field name="cust_order_ref" />
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Hope this will solve you problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I do not see any difference when adding the field in the parent object as well